# width , innerwidth , outwerwidth, all returns higher value than actual

Tags: jquery, outerwidth

On the page:
http://local.finerock.com/engagement-rings/halo-engagement-rings.html

I am using flexbox to display product filters, and used a small jquery to set child element width equal to its sibling, the code is like:

```
$(window).load(function(){
            if($(window).width() >= 900){
                $('.filter-options-content').width($('.filter-options-title').innerWidth());
            }
        });
```

still its taking longer width than actual, see screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP82u.png)

I have used all options, width, outerWidth & innerWidth, still the results are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my opinion, this is not the best way to creating dropdown items.

However, here is some fixing tips for you.

At first, don't give child elements width or height values with js.

**CSS**

custom.css:185

```
.block.filter .block-content.filter-content .filter-options-item {
    margin: 0 15px !important;
    flex: 1;
    max-width: 15% !important;
    position: relative; /* add line */
}
```

custom.css:210

```
.block.filter .block-content.filter-content .filter-options-item .filter-options-content, .catalog-product-view .product-options-wrapper .swatch-attribute .swatch-attribute-options {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #e8d4c1;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%; /* add line */
}
```

theme.css:6544

```
.page-layout-1column .block.filter .block-content.filter-content .block-filter-content {
    padding: 20px;
    max-height: calc(100% - 50px);
    overflow-y: auto; /* remove line */
}
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope you don't forget to give an upvote :)

Comment: similar kind of requirement is there, with different html structure, I tried applying the same logic here, by giving position relative to parent and width 100% to dropdown element, but its taking whole long width, any help would be appreciated

http://local.finerock.com/1-2-carat-round-baguette-shape-diamond-cushion-shaped-halo-ring-in-10k-gold-rg-12728.html

Comment: Well this is not the best way to creating dropdowns as I said before. 

Anyway. I just checked your project. Seems like that can cause bugs in the future, especially in responsive design. I have prepared a simple example for you that you can use in a much easier way. 

Please check: https://jsfiddle.net/caneroncel/7y9n4zgh/25/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it really made my day. thanks a ton.

Comment: You are welcome. So, please give an upvote to me.

Comment: I tried but Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to upvote because of less reputation count, thats why I accepted the answer and bookmarked this, as soon  as I get the required figures I will surely upvote it